# MVC concrete implementation

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm struggling to implement mvc based GUI's in Java. Actually I'm not unable to develop a GUI, but I'm not happy with my current mvc based (or at least I tried it) implementation. I read a lot about mvc but sometimes I get more confused than it will help me get a clearer mind.

Concrete, I implemented models which are observable and notify the observers (could be the controller or the view) when data changed. My controller and my view can access all models if necessary. The view has to implement an specific interface which the controller used to access the view (but don't have to know the specific implementation). The view is also observable and generates some defined events which then the controller (which observe the view) will process.

I realized that way a program which can be used to create a pdf document instead of writing this document in word. To be fast creating the document, the content of the document can be easily clicked together with the gui and maybe some changing of text in textfields. Therefore the GUI has many checkboxes and textfields etc. So how should I handle the manipulation of all textfields, checkboxes etc.? I could create for every changed textfield an event to the controller and deliver also the new text inside the textfield, the controller will put this to the coresponding model. But as my GUI has much textfields this would lead to much overhead of code.

My thoughts were then: The GUI actually shows only what is stored in the model, so if I change the textfield, the gui could store the new string direct in the model.

When the user no press the button to generate the pdf document, then an event is put to the controller which will do the necessary things to create from the stored data in the model the pdf.

I tried to make a short example how it works (ViewObserver and ViewObservable are a self implemented class and interface, similar to the existing Observer and Observable):

```
/*
 * Model
 */
public class Model extends Observable    
{
    private String title;
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
        super.setChanged();
        super.notifyObservers();
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
}

/*
 * View
 */
public class View extends ViewObservable implements ViewInterface, Observer
{
    private JTextField titleField;
    private Model model;

    public View(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.model.addObserver(this);            

        titleField = new JTextField("Title");
        txtTextPrice.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {updateTitle();}
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {updateTitle();}
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {updateTitle();}
            private void updateTitle()
            {
               model.setTitle(titleField.getText());
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) 
    {
        if(o.equals(model))
        {
            //get the data from the model and show it
            titleField .setText(model.getTitle());
        }    
    }
}

/*
 * Controller
 */
public class Controller implements ViewObserver
{
    private JTextField titleField;
    private Model model;

    public Controller(ViewInterface view, Model model)
    {
        view.addObserver(this);
        this.model = model;
        this.model.addObserver(this); 
    }

    /* 
     * Events from the view
     */
    @Override
    public void signalEvent(ViewEvent e, Object arg) 
    {
        //Generate here the the pdf document for example
        //if the corresponding event is thrown. Get the
        //necessary data from the models
    }
}
```

But I think there is a problem with my architecture or how are many events from the gui handled? If the listener of the buttons, checkboxes and textfields were in the controller, how could then the controller be independent of my view and how could the controller get all the data from all the textfields? Or did I missunderstood how a mvc should be implemented?

Comment: Perhaps you can post out your code structure or a short example of your code for example the code that handles the button that generates PDF, and how each MVC class handles your PDF generation?

Comment: OK, I tried to extract the necessary things out of the Model, View and Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one listener on all textfields in your panel. In that listener, you can get which textfield is triggered this event so you should be able to handle your logic on that listener. For other types of component, like button, it uses different listener type like actionListener. You should not have trouble on mixing them together. Generally speaking, Swing will use EDT thread to handle all the listeners invocation. It is a single thread model. Be sure not put too much overhead logic on the listeners. If you do so, the swing will through timeout exceptions. One solution is to use SwingWorker which is from JDK library.

Comment: What do you mean with panel? The view or the controller? My problem is, that I have much such textfields and I don't want to define for each textfield an event for the controller, thats why I choose the way of setting the new text direct in the model and don't loop over the controller.

Comment: Does the controller mean the listener added on the textfield? You can create one listener and add it on all the textfields. Or you can post your code.